# automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets doesn't work in embedded UITableViewController with UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

When you have a UITableView inside a UIViewController, you have to turn off the automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets flag (either in code or storyboard editor) to get the top space to not avoid the top bar. I now have a child UIViewController using an "embed" seque inside of a child view which contains a UITableView. I am seeing the "space" (the yellow area) yet I cleared all the flags in the embedded UIViewController and even cleared the flag manually in prepareForSeque, yet the space remains. Is there something else one has to do, or is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: This yellow area is a part of embedded VC or parent VC?

Comment: Embedded, thats the empty space at the top of the table view.

Comment: What is the frame of table view? Check it in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Exactly the height it should be. The yellow area is the background color of the table view. The table is 157 and the parent view is 173 and a storyboard sets the height of the parent view to 173 and constraints sets the table to be indented by 8 on all sides so the table is the correct size. It's just the scroll view inset is being applied despite being told not to.

Comment: Can't reduce this to code. It's mostly in a storyboard. Create a UINavigationController with a single UIViewController. Add a small Container View from the palette. Put a UITableViewController inside the child (which is connected to the container via an Embed seque. Wire up the table to show some data. Make the table's background to yellow so you can see it. Use constraints to make sure everything sizes

Comment: Ok, I'll try at home

Comment: Yep, I see it. 
Solution: set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO for **parent** VC, not embedded VC.

Comment: Bizarre. I will try it later today when I hook up that code again.

Answer (score 7):

Had this issue this morning.

Turns out, you need to uncheck *automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets* property from *parentViewController* instead of child when you are using embedded view controller mode like you did.

Here is my UI structure:

**ParentViewController** has a container view which point to **ChildViewController** (subclass of *UITableViewController*).

> Uncheck automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets in **ChildViewController**: doesn't work
>
> Uncheck automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets in **ParentViewController**: works!

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this for hours until I realized that the answer by @user3188985 was what was happening, though the solution did not work for me.

This is because I have two contained view controllers that each contain scrollViews, and I want one to adjust, and one not, what to do?

---

Well if you turn off auto adjustment in the parent controller, then you must manually adjust the one scrollView that you need, e.g. setting contentInset on appropriate cases.

---

If you leave on auto adjustment in the parent, I have found that a dummy scrollView, with a zero frame, hidden, all scroll properties set to NO, and if it is before your visible/enabled scrollView in the child view controller view hierarchy, then it will receive the auto adjustment, and leave your visible scrollView view alone.

Alternatively, you can just have your contained view controller's top most view be a scrollView with scrolling disabled, and have it contain another scrollView with scrolling enabled, this will achieve the same thing as the "dummy" approach.

---

What you can see here, is that the auto adjustment flag of only the parent view controller is taken into account, but it's own view controller hierarchy is traversed to find scrollViews to adjust in each contained controller. This is simply unwanted UIKit behavior. It would be nice each child controller's auto adjust setting was checked before deciding to mess with it :/